# Spring MVC Hibernate Error:HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

This is the error i got while deploying a spring mvc hibernate application to tomcat server in bluemix
 Error:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
    type Exception report
    message Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
    exception
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appointmentcontroller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private e.hospital.dao.Appointmentdao e.hospital.controller.appointmentcontroller.appointmentdaointerface; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private e.hospital.dao.Appointmentdao e.hospital.controller.appointmentcontroller.appointmentdaointerface; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:362)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1002)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:236)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:392)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:362)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1002)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the
```

Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 logs.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 :

```
    Trying to run this application on a tomcat server .
```

My spring-servlet.xml file is :

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="e.hospital" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
            p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="configurationClass">
                <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven />
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>
     <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
           <property name="basename" value="props" />
        </bean>  
    </beans>
```

My web.xml file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping> 
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

jdbc.properties file :

```
    jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=mysql://uxU8DpQLzXbFx:pWDZqUGanMILT@192.155.247.249:3307/d1c11bcab8a884281b396673ca9cb835e
    jdbc.username=uxU8DpQLzXbFx
    jdbc.password=pWDZqUGanMILT
```

hibernate.cfg.xml file :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
           <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.LoginBean" />
            <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.PatientRegisterBean" />
            <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.AppointmentBean" />
            <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.DoctorBean" />
            <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.LeaveBean" />
            <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.ProfileBean" />
            <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.ScheduleBean" />
            <mapping class="e.hospital.bean.SlotBean" />
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

[image]

Please let me know if you have any idea on this error.

Comment: Please format your post and put only relevant information. It is just stack trace.

Comment: Just throwing your error up is probably the worst thing to do when you need help.

Comment: I agree with others, please at least format and separate your files - if you help identify the problem, it'd be a lot easier to find/get a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading stacktraces, I normally go straight to the bottom as I find in 90% of times, the main cause is the last thing logged.
In your case the following is the at the end of the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
```

And I'd guess this would be your problem. Looks like you are missing a jar in your deployment or environment containing the apache commons dbcp classes.

But I agree with the other comments, and the general down voting - you really need to lay your question out better.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your question and from the stacktrace,

> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:
>   Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean
>   with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

It fails to create the `dataSource` that you have configured in your `spring-servlet.xml` because it says `ClassNotFoundException` on `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` so please check if you have the relevant `apache` `dbcp` jar included in the project lib / classpath.

If you are using `maven` then you can try adding this,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @ShwetaPuchu whats that?

Comment: hi Thanks for your help.I am getting one more error now :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.isDefaultJndiEnvironmentAvailable()Z. Could you please help in this case ?..Do i need to add one more dependency or modify my spring version ?

Comment: @ShwetaPuchu seems to be you are missing some dependencies but can not figure it out from this. However please accept this answer as it solved your initial error.